# SQL Server Integration Services Merge Join not working for multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, ssis, inner-join

I'm using SSIS to merge join sql server data (left) and oracle data (right).  Both data sets are sorted at source before merge join.  It works fine when the oracle source returns only one row, but not when it returns multiple rows.  It's not returning data after Merge Join even though there are several rows have matching data.  Here is my flow:

[image: SSIS Data Flow]

[image: SSIS Merge Join Task]

More Information:

Both are pre sorted (order by in source queries). The oracle source column `EXTERNLAL_ID` is cast as integer i.e. `CAST(EXTERNAL_ID AS INTEGER)` in the query, so both join keys ended up as DT_I4 before Merge Join.

Example: SQL Server source has three rows with `UNIQUEID`: 1,2,3 and Oracle source has one row with `EXTERNAL_ID`:1, `Oracle_UNIQUE_ID`:999; Merge Join returns one row as expected with SQL Server `UNIQUEID`:1, `EXTERNAL_ID`:1 and `ORACLE_UNIQUE_ID`:999.  If SQL Server source has three rows with `UNIQUEID`: 1,2,3 and Oracle source has two rows with `EXTERNAL_ID`:1,2 and `ORACLE_UNIQUE_ID`:999,998; Merge Join is not returning any data.

Comment: your *join key* for the oracle db is not `ORACLE_UNIQUE_ID`

Comment: Yes, it's not.  Join key for Oracle is external_id (sort order 1).

Comment: Has the data been pre sorted?, i.e. in an ORDER BY in both queries? Do the SSIS data types match?

Comment: Both are pre sorted (order by in source queries).  The oracle source column EXTERNLAL_ID is cast as integer i.e. CAST(EXTERNAL_ID AS INTEGER) in the query, so both join keys ended up as DT_I4 before Merge Join.

Comment: Two questions: What is the data conversion transform, specifically: does it impact the key column? Also: What is the container around the Oracle data source and merge join?

Comment: Do you see anything strange if you add Data Viewers on the two sources immediately before the merge?

Comment: Brian, data conversion to integer is on the key column, in this case it is EXTERNAL_ID.  The container around the Oracle data source and merge join is simple grouping, nothing special.

Comment: Matt, I did not see any strange in data viewer on two sources.  I see all the data as expected in oracle source even when it returns multiple rows.  Is using CAST column as Join Key not a good option?

Comment: Help me understand when it works and when it doesn't. You have 3 rows coming from SQL Server, IDs 1, 2, 3 and one from Oracle: ID 2. Output is one row-the match for 2. Now when there are multiple rows from Oracle, what happens and what are you expecting? Are there two rows with ID 2 and you'd expect it to match both from SQL Server or is it the case the you have IDs 2 and 3 but only one of those matches a SQL Server row.

Comment: Go ahead and update your question with this and the other information. Comments are ephemeral whereas questions have versioning

Answer (score 2):

If the data type of either source is VARCHAR() rather than INT, the sorting may not act as you expect.  Consider the following:

```
DECLARE @SampleTable TABLE (IntegerID INT, CharacterID VARCHAR(3))

INSERT INTO @SampleTable (IntegerID, CharacterID)

SELECT 1,1 UNION 
SELECT 2,2 UNION 
SELECT 12,12 UNION 
SELECT 122,122 UNION 
SELECT 3,3 UNION 
SELECT 133,133 UNION 
SELECT 31,31 UNION 
SELECT 321,321 


SELECT * FROM @SampleTable ORDER BY IntegerID

SELECT * FROM @SampleTable ORDER BY CharacterID
```

The first SELECT, which sorts by a known integer, returns the data in the following order:

```
1
2
3
12
31
...
```

The second SELECT, which sorts by a character field (that just happens to contain a number), returns data in the following order:

```
1
12
122
133
2
3
...
```

Your SSIS task, which only sees the CAST() statement in your SELECT, assumes that when you sorted the data, you sorted it as an integer.  Your SQL statement sorted it by the character version, not caring about the fact that you returned an integer with your SELECT statement.

Assuming I'm correct, to fix this you need to sort the data on the source system as an integer, i.e., `ORDER BY CAST(EXTERNAL_ID AS INTEGER)`.